# NavBar not showing up in second and third viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabview

I am trying to add Navigation bar to my tabbar view controllers.But, it is showing up in firstViewController but not in the other two views. Any reason why this is not working?

```
self.firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil fileName:@"firstPlist"];
self.firstVC.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first"];
self.firstNavBarController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.firstVC];

self.secondVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil fileName:@"secondPlist"];
self.secondVC.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];
self.secondNavBarController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.secondVC];


self.thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"thirdView" bundle:nil fileName:@"thirdPlist"];
self.thirdVC.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"third"];
self.thirdNavBarController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.thirdVC];
```

Comment: `self.secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil fileName:@"secondPlist"]` a typo ?

Comment: @Chancy Sorry, I don't see any typo here.

Comment: Actually I am using the same view controller (FirstViewController) for the first and second tab.

Comment: @Sage show your code where you adding these viewControllers to UITabBarController

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre thanks. I got it. It was my mistake while adding these to the tabBar.   Here is what I fixed now and it is working fine. Thanks so much for pointing me to the right direction. 

            self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[self.firstNavBarController, self.secondNavBarController, self.thirdNavBarController];